# I would be thankful if you + did/do/could do?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

There are three structures that I remember but can't say if they are correct or say the differences.
I would be thankful if you could tell me!

> 1. **I would be very thankful if you spend** your time on this.
> 2. **I would be very thankful if you spent** your time on this.
> 3. **I would be very thankful if you could/would spend** your time on this.

Comment: Construction 1 is ungrammatical, whereas 2 and 3 sound good, with 3 being even more tentative/polite (and, in my experience as a non-native speaker of English, more common), and with *would* being the usual choice, even though there isn't much difference between *could* and *would* there. Moreover, you'd usually see *grateful* there instead of *thankful*. In a very formal style, all the words are spelled out as in your examples; in a neutral/informal style, the *would*s are shortened to just *'d*s: *I'd be very grateful if you'd...* – I'm not sure about the rest of your sentence(s).

Comment: @userr2684291 thank you, can we use the construction "I will be grateful if you do..." ?

Comment: Yes, but it's less polite than both 2 and 3.